# Hive "select to_date(column2) from tablename"

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I having the below table structure:

```
Table name: test
```

Table Structure:col1 and col2 are Strings here.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| "abc" | "15/04/2016" |
| "def" | "31/05/2016" |

When I am trying to execute the below, it is showing NULL as the result.

```
select to_date(col2) from test;
```

Any idea why it not showing the col2 result.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col2,'dd/MM/yyyy')))
```

`to_date(String timestamp)` expects timestamp to be in following format: **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**

Refer [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for more details.

Comment: When i am inserting the data into the string column of date then, NULL value is coming.. that is date is not loading into the table itself. the value has format "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: you mean col2 column or new date??